# Getting 'BSON field 'update.updates.collation' is the wrong type 'string', expected type 'object'' when trying to update document with _id

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When trying to update a document using `_id` from node js using mongoose model, getting below error.

> BSON field 'update.updates.collation' is the wrong type 'string', expected type 'object'

```
      Model.update({
          _id: new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(req.params.blogId),
          "comments._id":new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(req.params.commentId)
      },{
          "$set":{
              "comments.$.description": req.body.description
          }
      },function(err,doc){
          if(err){
              next(err);
              return;
          }          
          console.log("Commented updated successfully.");    
          res.send(doc);
      })
```

Schema:

```
const blogSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    createdDate: Date,
    lastUpdated: Date,
    author: {
        name: String,
        profession: String,
        description: String
    },
    tags: [String],
    comments:[{
        title:String,
        description:String,
        date:Date,
        username:String
    }]
},{
    collection:'Blogs'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error comes from your schema description. You can't use a `string` to define a *collation* with mongoose (and mongodb).

The *collation* property must be an object as defined in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/):

> A collation document has the following fields:

```
{
   locale: <string>,
   caseLevel: <boolean>,
   caseFirst: <string>,
   strength: <int>,
   numericOrdering: <boolean>,
   alternate: <string>,
   maxVariable: <string>,
   backwards: <boolean>
}
```

So in your case you have to update your schema definition like that for example (or remove the collation property):

```
const blogSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  createdDate: Date,
  lastUpdated: Date,
  author: {
    name: String,
    profession: String,
    description: String
  }, 
  tags: [String],
  comments:[{
    title: String,
    description: String,
    date: Date,
    username: String
  }]
}, { collation: { locale: 'en_US', strength: 1 } });
```

For more information checkout the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collation).